# SQL Server 2000 varchar(8000) truncate to 256?

Tags: sql-server-2000, varchar

I have SQL Server 2000 and I have a stored procedure that has `@output` as `varchar(8000)`
and I have a loop that keeps concatenate the result into `@output` and at the end I made `select @output`

My problem is the output length is truncated to the first 256 characters only!!! Other characters (output) is missing.

I tried to use `TEXT` instead of `varchar` but I got an error

> The text, ntext, and image data types
>   are invalid for local variables.

Any idea is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to show us the code please. And accept some answers to your previous questions too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you are using query analyzer for this. If you do, most probably this is a setting problem. In query analyzer options, try to find the setting for maximum number of characters displayed in each column, set it higher, for example to 8000.

Comment: In fact i tried query analyzer after getting the same result of executing the SP using PHP code!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a limitation of your access method to the SQL connectivity.
MS SQL Query Analyzer says that such functionality works...

Sample procedure:

```
create procedure xTestPtoc 
  @InParam varchar(4000), @OutParam varchar(8000) out
as
  set @OutParam = @InParam + @InParam
go
```

Call code:

```
declare @InParam varchar(4000)
declare @i int
declare @OutParam varchar(8000)

select @i = 1270, @InParam = '', @OutParam = ''

while (@i > 0)
  select @InParam = @InParam + convert(varchar(10), @i), @i = @i - 1

select len(@InParam), @InParam

exec xTestPtoc @InParam, @OutParam out

select len(@OutParam), @OutParam
```

Result of sample code execution (I skip the full output of variables, of course):

```
----------- ---------------
3973        127012691268...
(1 row(s) affected)

----------- ---------------
7946        127012691268...
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default in older data access libs like ADO with ODBC column results truncate at 256 characters. To get more than 256 characters you have call a special method like GetChunk: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681747(v=VS.85).aspx